# File attachment button on InfoPath form not working for user but works for me?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, custom-list, attachments

I have an InfoPath form with a file attachment button but when a user tries to upload an attachment(clicks on the button)nothing happens. When I click the same button a dialog box to browse for a file to upload comes up. Is this a permission issue? I've granted her full control to the site/list but it is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you and the user using the same web browser, the same version of browser? Have you checked if either you or the user is running the InfoPath form in compatibility mode assuming you are using IE?

Comment: How do I check for compatibility mode?

Comment: The compatibility mode is available in Internet Explorer browsers only. To access the compatibility settings, you go to **Menu bar** > **Tools** > **Compatibility View Settings**. In the window that pops up check that you and the user have the same settings.

Comment: Hi Mihail, thank you so much for your help. Am I looking for the browser tools or tools in SharePoint? Sorry, I'm really new at this.

Comment: Also, I just had the user log into SharePoint on my machine and the same thing is happening. Could this be a permission issue?

Comment: Ok, I found Compatibility View Settings. There isn't anything listed.

Comment: If the user experiences the same issue on your machine, then it is definitely a permission issue. I presume the InfoPath form is attached to a SharePoint list of some sort. Make sure the user has at least **Contribute** permission to the list. In the case the InfoPath form stores the files uploaded in a specific library, then make sure the user has **Contribute** permission to that library.

Comment: Hi. Ok, its good now! It was a permission issue. Thank you so much for all your help!!

Comment: "Contribute" (which will definitely solve this issue) is an out of the box permission level that may grant more permissions than the user may actually need (for example, "Delete"). I know I am late to the party, but see my answer below for the exact permission change required to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an issue with InfoPath and SharePoint permissions.**

When you use the attachment control on a SharePoint list that has been customised to use an InfoPath form, the attachment control behaves differently than to the default out-of-the-box SharePoint list form..

The user needs both "Add New Item" & "Edit Item" Permissions to use the Attachments control on an InfoPath customised SharePoint list form.

*These permissions are not enough to allow SharePoint list Attachments with a customised InfoPath form (but are enough for a default SharePoint list with no InfoPath customisations):*

[image: No Edit]

*These permissions will allow SharePoint list Attachments with a customised InfoPath form:*

[image: Yes Edit]

This is really frustrating, as if you do not use an InfoPath form, the list Attachment is readily available (albeit in the ribbon) for users that only have "Add New Item" permissions, and not "Edit Item" permissions.

*Ribbon for InfoPath Form customised list:*

[image: Form Customised Ribbon]

*Ribbon for default SharePoint list form with no InfoPath customisations:*

[image: SharePoint Default Ribbon]

*(Side note, unrelated to this question)*

I ran into this issue recently when I created an InfoPath form for users whom I did not want to be able to edit their submissions after posting an item.

I got around this issue by granting the user "Edit Item" permissions, and then creating a Content Type that used another InfoPath form with read only fields, and switching to this content type with a SharePoint Designer Workflow that ran on item creation. This effectively made any edit attempts useless.