# Attachment button not working on InfoPath Form for SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, infopath, custom-form, attachments

I have created a custom InfoPath form with an attachment button.

When the last drop-down is yes then only the attachment section appears.

The problem is when this is clicked, a grey overlay appears which doesn't allow anything to be clicked within the page at all.

Any help, please.
I am using SharePoint Server 2016
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So making changes to the permissions didn't work at all.
In the end, I did a little bit of a workaround which didn't involve InfoPath at all.

I created a piece of Javascript which I added to NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx, which stops users from saving if no attachment is present

script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function PreSaveAction() {

if (document.getElementById('idAttachmentsRow').style.display=='none' )

{alert('Attachments are Mandatory! Please attach the relevant Self-Assessment Checklist using the Attcah File button at the top of the page.');

return false ;}

else {  return true;  }
}

/script>

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a permission issue and known issue in infopath form.

This is an issue with InfoPath and SharePoint permissions.

When you use the attachment control on a SharePoint list that has been customised to use an InfoPath form, the attachment control behaves differently than to the default out-of-the-box SharePoint list form..

The user needs both "Add New Item" & "Edit Item" Permissions to use the Attachments control on an InfoPath customised SharePoint list form.

These permissions are not enough to allow SharePoint list Attachments with a customised InfoPath form (but are enough for a default SharePoint list with no InfoPath customisations):

Similar question is discussed below :

[File attachment button on InfoPath form not working for user but works for me?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165171/file-attachment-button-on-infopath-form-not-working-for-user-but-works-for-me)

Comment: I've had a look at this and I myself have the issue, despite having Full Control over the SharePoint Site
Is there an alternative way to have he attachment as  a button instead of in the ribbon at the top